# SQL Server Group By - Aggregate NULL or empty values into all other values

Tags: sql-server, group-by, null

I am trying to group by a column. The problem is that the NULL values of the column are grouped as a separate group.

I want the NULL values to be added to each of the other group values instead.

Example of a table:

[image: example of a table]

The results I want to get from group by with sum aggregation over the 'val' column:

[image: the results i want to get from group by with sum aggregation over the 'val' column]

Can anyone help me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can precalculate the value to spread through the rows and then just do arithmetic:

```
select t.id,
       sum(t.val) + (null_sum / cnt_id)
from t cross join
     (select count(distinct id) as cnt_id,
             sum(case when id is null then val else 0 end) as null_sum
      from t
     ) tt
group by t.id;
```

Note some databases do integer division, so you might need `null_sum * 1.0 / cnt_id`.

Answer (score 0):

A `GROUP BY` operation can't really generate values for each group on the fly, so logically you need records which are missing to really be present. 
 One approach is to use a calendar table to generate a table containing one `NULL` record for each `id` group:

```
WITH ids AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT id FROM yourTable
    WHERE id IS NOT NULL
),
cte AS (
    SELECT t1.id, t2.val
    FROM ids t1
    CROSS JOIN yourTable t2
    WHERE t2.id IS NULL
)

SELECT t.id, SUM(t.val) AS val
FROM
(
    SELECT id, val FROM yourTable WHERE id IS NOT NULL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT id, val FROM cte
) t
GROUP BY
    id;
```

### Demo

Comment: Thank you! my problem is that i have more then one column in the grouping set... i tried your solution with some adjustments, but it too heavy...

Comment: It's not really heavy at all.  You need to generate missing rows somehow, and this is one straightforward way.